# Magento2: Local-Storage Mage-Storage and Mage-Cache Empty on every Reload

Tags: magento2, javascript, session, customer-session, local-storage

Many features in my web page break as when I investigated, I found out that
many local storage keys don't even exist now which used to exist before.

list of keys that don't exist:

- lo_session
- mage-banners-cache-storage
- mage-banners-cache-timeout
- mage-cache-storage
- mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation
- mage-cache-timeout
  ...
  and many more

What could be the reason and how to fix it.